# Why debugging does not work in subprojects in .NET Aspire deployments?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-8.0, dotnet-aspire

I was trying to set up a simple .NET Aspire project to test how it works following [this tutorial from Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/aspire/get-started/quickstart-build-your-first-aspire-app?tabs=dotnet-cli). Aspire workload for Visual Studio [will be available in 17.9 onwards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/aspire/get-started/quickstart-build-your-first-aspire-app?tabs=dotnet-cli#:%7E:text=Visual%20Studio%202022%20Preview%20version%2017.9%20or%20higher%20(Optional)), but the current stable Visual Studio release is 17.8, so I decided to go around with the second option, using dotnet CLI.

I created the project and built that. Everything was going well, the dashboard, the projects, the Redis cache, etc.

But when I tried to build the `AspireSample.AppHost` project with debugging and I attached a breakpoint to somewhere in the Blazor project, I got this error:

[image: Breakpoint error]

This problem happened to the Blazor project's `Program.cs` file too:

[image: Breakpoint error in Program.cs]

And, as you might have guessed, the solution provided in the tooltip did not help. This problem is only present in Non-AppHost projects. If I attach a debugger to the AppHost's Program.cs, it will work.

Does anyone know why it is not able to identify the Projects for debugging, and of course, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go to Debug/Attach to Process..., search there by your project name and attach.

Comment: Hi. As mentioned in the documentation link in Microsoft Learn, the Redis cache is running on Docker, but the projects are being run on machine.